# Unable to execute omnet++ files

Tags: omnet++

I have just begun to use OMNET++ and got stuck in the first place.

This is the error which I get each time : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbttB.jpg)

Please tell me how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You have probably download Linux version of `OMNeT++` or there were errors during unpacking the package. Download the Windows version of `OMNeT++`, unzip it and try again build it.